Cleaning up inactive service principles in Azure Entra
I'm trying to (as the title suggests) clean up unused service principles in Azure entra as per the compliance, azure defender and advisor recommendations.
This is a pre-cursor to me applying for ISO compliance certification for the business.
Having got some advice from Chat GPT it's given me this broken script ...
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD

# Export users with last sign-in date
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | ForEach-Object {
    $user = $_
    $lastSignIn = (Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$($user.UserPrincipalName)'" | Sort-Object createdDateTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).createdDateTime
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
        LastSignInDateTime = $lastSignIn
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\InactiveUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation

# Import the CSV file with inactive users
$inactiveUsers = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\InactiveUsers.csv"

# Disable users
foreach ($user in $inactiveUsers) {
    if ($user.LastSignInDateTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)) {
        Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $user.UserPrincipalName -AccountEnabled $false
    }
} 

... I have several issues / questions here ...

Is this a good idea?
The script doesn't work so I need help fixing it
I'm surprised there's no means to handle what it seems should be a routine task in the UI, am I missing something?

I was thinking if I skip dropping the initial set to a file I could just re-run this on an automation account as a scheduled task, is this a good or bad idea?

For sample, I passed two service principals and got the inactive service principals in the response like this and you can delete the service principal. If this works for you, I will post an answer. (passed only 2 service principals as for whole tenant it takes lot of time)

You can modify the script to filter only Enterprise applications and check the inactive SPs $servicePrincipals = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All:$true | ? {$_.Tags -eq "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp"} 

In my tenant I have few Enterprises applications:

To fetch the inactive Service Principals from 3 days, I used the below script:
# Retrieve all service principals
$servicePrincipals = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All:$true | ? {$_.Tags -eq "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp"} 

# Define threshold for inactivity (e.g., 6 months)
$inactiveThreshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)

# Array to store inactive service principals
$inactiveServicePrincipals = @()

# Check each service principal for activity
foreach ($sp in $servicePrincipals) {
    # Determine if the service principal has any recent activity
    $recentActivity = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "appId eq '$($sp.AppId)'" | Sort-Object createdDateTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

    if ($recentActivity -eq $null) {
        # No recent activity found for the service principal
        $inactiveServicePrincipals += $sp
    }
}

# Output inactive service principals
$inactiveServicePrincipals | Select-Object DisplayName, AppId


The app with name Multi-tenant dint not display in the response has there was a user interaction:

Now you can delete the inactive Service Principals also by modifying the script like below:
# Retrieve all service principals tagged as WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp
$servicePrincipals = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All:$true | Where-Object { $_.Tags -eq "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp" }

# Define threshold for inactivity (e.g., 6 months)
$inactiveThreshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)  # Adjust as needed

# Array to store inactive service principals
$inactiveServicePrincipals = @()

# Check each service principal for activity
foreach ($sp in $servicePrincipals) {
    # Determine if the service principal has any recent activity
    $recentActivity = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "appId eq '$($sp.AppId)'" | Sort-Object createdDateTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

    if ($recentActivity -eq $null) {
        # No recent activity found for the service principal
        $inactiveServicePrincipals += $sp
    }
}

# Output inactive service principals
$inactiveServicePrincipals | Select-Object DisplayName, AppId

# Delete inactive service principals
foreach ($inactiveSP in $inactiveServicePrincipals) {
    Write-Host "Deleting $($inactiveSP.DisplayName) with AppId $($inactiveSP.AppId)..."
    Remove-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $inactiveSP.ObjectId -Force
}

Write-Host "Deletion complete."


The inactive Service Principals got deleted successfully:

If the tenant has many Service principals, then the script might throw a throttled error, hence try the below code:
# Retrieve all service principals tagged as WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp
$servicePrincipals = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All:$true | Where-Object { $_.Tags -eq "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp" }

# Define threshold for inactivity 
$inactiveThreshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)  # Adjust as needed

# Array to store inactive service principals
$inactiveServicePrincipals = @()

# Function to handle retry logic
function Invoke-RetryableOperation {
    param (
        [ScriptBlock]$Operation,
        [int]$MaxRetries = 3
    )

    $retryCount = 0
    $retryAfter = 10  # Default retry time in seconds

    while ($retryCount -lt $MaxRetries) {
        try {
            & $Operation
            return $true
        } catch {
            if ($_.Exception.Message.Contains("throttled")) {
                Write-Host "Throttling encountered. Retrying after $retryAfter seconds..."
                Start-Sleep -Seconds $retryAfter
                $retryAfter = 2 * $retryAfter  # Exponential backoff strategy
                $retryCount++
            } else {
                Write-Error "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
                return $false
            }
        }
    }

    Write-Error "Operation failed after $MaxRetries retries."
    return $false
}

# Check each service principal for activity
foreach ($sp in $servicePrincipals) {
    $appId = $sp.AppId

    # Function to get recent activity for a service principal
    function Get-RecentActivity {
        $logs = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "appId eq '$appId'" | Sort-Object createdDateTime -Descending
        return $logs | Select-Object -First 1
    }

    # Attempt to get recent activity, with retry logic
    $retryableOperation = {
        Get-RecentActivity
    }

    $recentActivity = Invoke-RetryableOperation -Operation $retryableOperation

    # Check if no recent activity found within threshold
    if ($recentActivity -eq $null -or $recentActivity.createdDateTime -lt $inactiveThreshold) {
        $inactiveServicePrincipals += $sp
    }
}

# Output inactive service principals
$inactiveServicePrincipals | Select-Object DisplayName, AppId

It will take sometime to fetch the Service Principals:

In my environment total 240 applications are present in which 215 are inactive from 7 days:

$inactiveServicePrincipals | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count


I dint delete the Service Principals, to delete you can add below script:
# Delete inactive service principals
foreach ($inactiveSP in $inactiveServicePrincipals) {
    Write-Host "Deleting $($inactiveSP.DisplayName) with AppId $($inactiveSP.AppId)..."
    Remove-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $inactiveSP.ObjectId -Force
}
Write-Host "Deletion complete."

